# Роутинг в kohana?

Tags: роутинг, kohana

На данный момент у меня 3 роута (последний не в счет, так что по сути 2):

```
Route::set('applications', 'applications(/<url>)', array('url' => '.+'))
        ->defaults(array(
            'controller' => 'subject',
            'action'     => 'index',        
    ));

Route::set('web', 'web(/<url>)', array('url' => '.+'))
        ->defaults(array(
            'controller' => 'subject',
            'action'     => 'index',        
    ));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'main',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Из всего этого следует что юзер перейдя по ссылкам `mysite/web` и `mysite/application` попадает (условно) на контролллер `subject` и метод `action_index`.

Вопрос, как сделать так чтобы если юзер перейдя по всем остальным ссылкам вида:

```
mysite/A 
mysite/B
...
mysite/Z
```

т.е. разным всяким, попадал в этот же контроллер `subject`, но уже в другой метод, допустим метод `test`? Но 1-ые два роута должны все-равно срабатывать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Те, кто говорят, что у Kohana нет документации - [врут](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/).

[Маршрутизация](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing) поддерживает регулярные выражения:

```
Route::set('magic_route', '<magic>',  array('magic' => '(A|B|C)'))
  ->defaults(array(
      // контроллер, метод
  ));
```

Как проверить значение парамера вы уже знаете.

P.S.: какой смысл из `array('url' => '.+')`? Параметр `url` у вас необязательный, а значит, если ничего не будет - всё ок, а если что-то будет - всё равно регулярка выполнится.